# WIX Undefined preprocessor variable

Tags: wix, wix3.5

Using WIX I cannot seem to get my variables to work - any ideas?

I'm using:  WIX version 3.5 and Visual Studio 2010

Here is the error I am getting ( This is the output from visual studio ):

> ------ Build started: Project: InstallProject, Configuration: Debug x86 ------ "C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin\heat.exe"
>   dir "c:\publish\ems" -cg EMSPublishedFiles -gg -scom -sreg -sfrag -srd
>   -dr INSTALLLOCATION -var env.EMS_PUBLISHDIR -out "C:\Projects\ems\Trunk\Code\Installer\InstallProject\Fragments\FilesFragment.wxs"
>   Microsoft (R) Windows Installer Xml Toolset Harvester version
>   3.5.2519.0 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin\candle.exe
>   -**dEMS_PUBLISHDIR=c:\publish\ems** -dDebug -d"DevEnvDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\"
>   -dSolutionDir=C:\Projects\ems\Trunk\Code\Installer\ -dSolutionExt=.sln -dSolutionFileName=InstallProject.sln -dSolutionName=InstallProject -dSolutionPath=C:\Projects\ems\Trunk\Code\Installer\InstallProject.sln -dConfiguration=Debug -dOutDir=Packages\ -dPlatform=x86 -dProjectDir=C:\Projects\ems\Trunk\Code\Installer\InstallProject\ -dProjectExt=.wixproj -dProjectFileName=InstallProject.wixproj -dProjectName=InstallProject -dProjectPath=C:\Projects\ems\Trunk\Code\Installer\InstallProject\InstallProject.wixproj
>   -dTargetDir=C:\Projects\ems\Trunk\Code\Installer\InstallProject\Packages\
>   -dTargetExt=.msi -dTargetFileName=EMSSetup.msi -dTargetName=EMSSetup -dTargetPath=C:\Projects\ems\Trunk\Code\Installer\InstallProject\Packages\EMSSetup.msi
>   -out obj\Debug\Fragments\ -arch x86 -ext "C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin\WixUtilExtension.dll" -ext "C:\Program
>   Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin\WixUIExtension.dll" -ext
>   "C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin\WixSqlExtension.dll"
>   -ext "C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin\WixIIsExtension.dll" Fragments\FilesFragment.wxs

**C:\Projects\ems\Trunk\Code\Installer\InstallProject\Fragments\FilesFragment.wxs(6,0): error CNDL0150: Undefined preprocessor variable '$(env.EMS_PUBLISHDIR)'.**

Its also worth noting that even though I have defined variables in Visual studios project properties : Proceessor variables ( EMS_PUBLISHDIR=c:\publish\ems; ) if I put the variable name in the project prebuild event $(EMS_PUBLISHDIR) I get an empty string.
I checked the project file directory using notepad and the declations for debug / release etc all look ok.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that this is being run from Visual Studio?  I see a call to candle, which I don't see in my runs from within Votive.  I had a similar issue which was caused when building the installer using a build server.  The variable was lost in the additional layer.  1) At the build server level 
2) At the MSBuild level 
3) What was recognized by the wixproj.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an environment variable, rather than a WiX variable.

`$(env.EMS_PUBLISHDIR)` - Looks for the Environment variable `EMS_PUBLISHDIR`
`$(var.EMS_PUBLISHDIR)` - Looks for the variable defined via WiX

Answer (score 0):

If you define -dEMS_PUBLISHDIR=... in candle call it becomes $(var.EMS_PUBLISHDIR) within Wix, not $(env.EMS_PUBLISHDIR).